# Date range search using Java MVC Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, date-range, localdate

anyone can help me with this problem. I encounter a problem and I'm stuck with this.
I want to search all record using the Java Hibernate.

This is my model:

```
private LocalDate startDt = LocalDate.now();
    private LocalDate endDt = LocalDate.now();;
    public LocalDate getStartDt() {
        return startDt;
    }
    public void setStartDt(LocalDate startDt) {
        this.startDt = startDt;
    }
    public LocalDate getEndDt() {
        return endDt;
    }
    public void setEndDt(LocalDate endDt) {
        this.endDt = endDt;
    }
```

This is my view:

```
<form>
                        from <form:input path="start_date" type= "date" style="box-sizing:border-box; height:30px;"/>
                        to <form:input path="end_date" type= "date" style="box-sizing:border-box; height:30px"/>
                        <input type= "submit" class="btn btn-success" style=height:30px;/>
                        </form>
```

and lastly my Hibernate DAO:

```
if(sched.getStartDt()!=null && sched.getEndDt()!=null){
            dynamicSql.append("and   where ds.deliveryDate between :start_date AND :end_date");
        }
    Query hql = getSession().createQuery(sql);
if(sched.getStartDt()!=null && sched.getEndDt()!=null){
               hql.setParameter("start_date","%"+sched.getStartDt()+"%");
               hql.setParameter("end_date","%"+sched.getEndDt()+"%");
            }
```

Comment: Could you please tell us what exactly isn't working and where exactly you are stuck?

Comment: Why not just `hql.setParameter("start_date", sched.getStartDt());` (without the `%`)?

Comment: Hi sir @deHaar, the view page isn't showing due to the semantic error.

Comment: @OleV.V. won't work, I tried it for how many times.

Comment: Which semantic error is this? Can you show any error message or at least describe the undesired behaviour a little more in detail. The information about the page not showing is good, but won't help anyone to help you in this situation. That could be caused by anything...

Comment: The reason for the error is i can't understand to get the exact date for the **model** which i can i use for the **view**. 
I don't think if I also need to create another controller for this, since i have the **controller** to process the showing the table from the view @deHaar